# Numeric comparison with user input always produces "not equal" result

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, user-input, comparison-operators

I want to get a number input by the user via `input()` and compare it with a specific value, i.e., `3`.

However, I have the impression my if statement doesn't work. The comparison is always `False`.

```
Start = input()
if Start == 3:
     print ("successful")
```

Comment: You should check your tabs (I recomend you to use four spaces, not regular tabs and not to mix them). greetings

Answer (score 3):

Python 3 input function returns string.

Try like this

```
start = input("-->: ")
if start == "3":
    print("successful")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this as an alternative:

Adding **int** will convert the variable to int data type.

```
input = int(raw_input("Enter a num: "))
if input == 3:
   print "Successful"
```

Comment: This is how to do it in Python 2.x (however, it should be noted that the built-in function `input()` is shadowed).

Comment: okay then, maybe just an alternative. @moooeeeep, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

Some things you could do on your own to get to the root of the problem:

Ways to get to know the type of the object:

```
print(type(start)) # prints <class 'str'>
print(repr(start)) # prints '3'
```

Unlike Python 2.x, the function `input()` returns a string object (and does not blindly [evaluate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) the expression provided by the user):

> **input([***prompt***]):**
>
> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. **The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.** [...]

This should give an idea how to fix it (compare numbers to numbers).

For further reading:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr
- [How does Python compare string and int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3270680/1025391)
- [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/1025391)

Answer (score 0):

you should check your tabs (I recomend you to use four spaces, not regular tabs and not to mix them)

```
start = 0
start = input("-->:")
if start == "3":
    print("Success")
```